# Web Share API permission missing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement the Web Share Api functionality on my test web app but it doesn't seem I'm able to do it. This is the code:

```
const newVariable: any = navigator;
{newVariable && newVariable.share && <IconButton aria-label="Share" onClick={async (e) => {
try {
  const id = await shareRepository.shareTrip(this.props.todolist)
  const url = "https://something.com/share/" + id
  await newVariable.share({
      title: 'Check my todolist for ' + this.props.todolist.trip.departure + ' - ' + this.props.todolist.trip.arrival,
      text: 'Check my todolist for ' + this.props.todolist.trip.departure + ' - ' + this.props.todolist.trip.arrival,
      url: url,
  })
} catch (error) {
  alert(error)
}
}}>
<ShareIcon />
</IconButton>}
```

Every time I try on both Firefox and Safari for iOS, I'm getting an error saying:

> NotAllowedError: the request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

If on those browser I try to share something from google.com I get the native dialog to choose with which app to share.

I cannot understand why. On this page there is no discussion about permission: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share

UPDATE:

on Chrome for android works just fine, on Firefox for Android doesn't work. On Chrome, Firefox and Safari (which I believe they use safari engine all three) is only working if I pass `""` which means the page itself, or `"https://something.com/share/"`, it breaks If I pass `"https://something.com/share/"+id` :/

Comment: while searching I've met really simple demo on web share feature: https://mkonikov.com/web-share-testing/ and it works on my Chrome@Android. could you check it out on browsers you are getting NotAllowedError?

Comment: if I change my url with `''`even my code works. But I cannot understand what's wrong with my url

Comment: does it match domain where your code is hosted?

Comment: @skyboyer I wrote an update, basically: on Chrome for android works just fine, on Firefox for Android doesn't work. On Chrome, Firefox and Safari (which I believe they use safari engine all three) is only working if I pass `""` which means the page itself, or `"https://something.com/share/"`, it breaks If I pass `"https://something.com/share/"+id` :/

Comment: It's a Safari bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046434/how-to-use-webshareapi-preceded-by-an-ajax-call-in-safari/59881576#59881576

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understood what was the issue, which is absolutely annoying.

So:

```
  const id = await shareRepository.shareTrip(this.props.todolist)
```

This call is the one that is causing problems. If I comment it, on iOS there is no issue.

If I keep it I have no problem at all on Android but iOS will complain.

So I need to rethink the flow of the application to pass the id from outside the 'onClick' event.

Comment: aha! so since it make `share()` be run in separate [microtask](https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f) it means for browser that it was not initiated by click! so it looks like security violation to browser. make sense!

Comment: Yep. But I don't see any other way of getting a data a need for the share information :/

Comment: to many alternatives to be able fetching in advance? as a workaround you may for first click retrieve data + display additional popup so user would need click it(and then there will be no async action needed for `share()` and browser'd be fine)

Comment: Anyway. I don't understand why Chrome on Android didn't complain

Comment: maybe they have less strict check on that

Answer (score 12):

For other future users where the current answer is too specific to that code. The root issue is that the `share()` method must be called from a user gesture.

> If the method call was not triggered by user activation, return a promise rejected with with a "NotAllowedError" DOMException.
>   [From the Web Share API](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/#share-method).

---

A user activation is any of the following:

- change
- click
- contextmenu
- dblclick
- mouseup
- pointerup
- reset
- submit
- touchend

Comment: Just to add onto this, I was using the click event to update a vue watched variable in my 
 [share package](https://github.com/JJCLane/vue-web-sharer), it worked during tests but after consuming the package via npm it didn't. I switched to calling the method on the component directly and it worked.